# 12.04 backlight issue for Acer Aspire 5734z-4725 running on usb flash drive

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, acer, backlight

I have followed the fix found here: [Backlight can't be turn on in Acer Aspire 4736](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51301/backlight-issue)

However I can't use the `sudo update-grub2` command as it errors with

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)
```

As this laptop's hard drive is shot, I can't install the OS. So I'm using a live usb & I have been able to get it to temporarily work in Terminal with

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

I'm new to Ubuntu, so if you know how to fix this please provide as much detail to what I would need to do.

Answer (score -1):

fist off buy a hard drive............

secondly i have the same issue with my emachines e525 ( acer )

heres what google magic found for me. i dont know if it works... it makes no sense to me but i thought id drop it here b4 i go try.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900024

I wont be back so good luck lol

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.