# Backlight does not work on Toshiba portege and LTS 12.04

Tags: 12.04, backlight, toshiba

I have a Toshiba portege. Since some time I try to enable the backlit function but without success. I found several posts that should solve it, for example:

[Backlight can't be turn on in Acer Aspire 4736](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51301/backlight-issue)

but it didn't work for me (although now I can set the screen brightness!). I have LTS 12.04. My /etc/rc.local is here:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.b=00
exit 0
```

and my `/etc/default/grub` here:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Thank you for your comments and help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works. It adds a couple things more to you grub file.
http://www.gaggl.com/2012/05/intel-ultrabook-tweaks-on-ubuntu-12-04/
The **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX** line should end up like this

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1  i915.lvds_downclock=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor elevator=noop"

And of course you should run `sudo update-grub`

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, sorry for my late reply. I didn't have a look in long time. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The worse of all is that now my laptop seems to have problems when waking up after suspend or closing the lid....I will have to solve that one soon, it is really annoying